# My first api request always fails after page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, react-hooks

I'm having a problem with my API request that always fails after page load. Don't really know where Im wrong.

Here's my request and I call it when I interact with handleOpen function.

```
  const stock = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://morningstar1.p.rapidapi.com/live-stocks/GetRawRealtimeFigures',
    params: {Mic: props.mic, Ticker: clickedElement.ticker},
    headers: {
      'x-rapidapi-key': 'XXX',
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'morningstar1.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
  }

  const getStock = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.request(stock);
        return res.data;
    }
    catch (error) {
      setOpen(false);
      console.error("catch api error: ", error);
    }
  }

  const handleOpen = name => {
    
    let findClickedStock = props.stocksArray.find(item => item.ticker === name)
    setClickedElement(findClickedStock)

    getStock().then((dataFromStockApi) => {
      let combined1 = { ...dataFromStockApi, ...findClickedStock }
      setStockObject(combined1);

    });
    setOpen(true);
  };
```

ERROR:
[image: Error:]

Comment: ```404``` indicates that there is no such url. Make sure your url is correct. You can use some software for help(eg. postman). It makes the request checking faster. Also, pay attention to what the error msg shown. There might be sth to do with ```SearchBar.js``` line 100

Comment: It has nothing to do with react or axios ... something is wrong with your api-endpoint ... test your endpoint in postman first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your Ticker parameter is empty.

When you create "stock", `clickedElement.ticker` is undefined.

Do this:

```
    // pass name in as a parameter
    getStock(name).then(...)
```

Make getStock like like this:

```
  const getStock = async (ticker) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.request({
         method: 'GET',
         url: 'https://morningstar1.p.rapidapi.com/live-stocks/GetRawRealtimeFigures',
         params: {Mic: props.mic, Ticker: ticker},
         headers: {
           'x-rapidapi-key': 'XXX',
           'x-rapidapi-host': 'morningstar1.p.rapidapi.com'
         }
      });

      return res.data;
    }
    catch (error) {
      setOpen(false);
      console.error("catch api error: ", error);
    }
  }
```